# My newly posted Windows Store App Crash on startup

Tags: c#, uwp, app-store

I've write an app and posted it to the Windows Store as a beta.
The app is design to search drive for files and folders.

I build the app using UWP, C#, VS PRO 2022

My problem is that the App, when installed from the Windows Store (Windows 11), crash on startup.
I've try to find detail about the problem, but I can't find the specific error.
From the Parter Center it is stated this:

> fail_fast_exception_c0000602_frisk.beta.dll!system::text::json::serialization::metadata::reflectionmemberaccessor::__c__displayclass7_0$1_system::_*canon*._createpropertygetter_b__0

From the Windows Event viewer a found this:

> - Faulting application name: Frisk.Beta.exe, version: 0.1.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x6452d703
> - Faulting module name: mrt100_app.dll, version:
>   2.2.28604.0, time stamp: 0x5e38c6b4
> - Exception code: 0xc0000602 Fault offset: 0x000000000003f729 Faulting process ID: 0x0xB48C Faulting
>   application start time: 0x0x1D9A6C25D55EC14 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\SolutionsLaumieinc.Frisk-BetaEdition_0.1.11.0_x64__he4x4rq7qkny4\Frisk.Beta.exe
> - Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2_2.2.28604.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mrt100_app.dll
> - Report ID: 0e0bc8db-fab2-4bb9-8b90-2b3adc8746d0 Faulting package full
> - name: SolutionsLaumieinc.Frisk-BetaEdition_0.1.11.0_x64__he4x4rq7qkny4
> - Faulting package-relative application ID: App

And this

> Fault bucket 1563167420074679169, type 5 Event Name: MoAppCrash
> Response: Not available Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1:
> SolutionsLaumieinc.Frisk-BetaEdition_0.1.11.0_x64__he4x4rq7qkny4 P2:
> praid:App P3: 0.1.0.0 P4: 6452d703 P5: mrt100_app.dll P6: 2.2.28604.0
> P7: 5e38c6b4 P8: c0000602 P9: 000000000003f729 P10:
>
> Attached files:
>
> - \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.f54973d6-9fcf-4217-97e2-46133653c148.tmp.dmp
> - \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.59b9127a-5f02-4f7f-a945-4482ff0fad9a.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
> - \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.57c6453e-d380-4797-a80b-d301cc266659.tmp.csv
> - \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.64b62b34-0a8f-4c43-acd7-b90315bc0244.tmp.txt
> - \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER.e8d5e522-a9bc-4dad-930c-4ab9f8ecd98f.tmp.xml
>
> These files may be available here:
>
> - \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_SolutionsLaumiei_43290d98e4c918fd139c22b70cba3e1931a102e_e6f179f6_a41e0083-1fb2-4052-981b-7528893d879e
>
> Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
> f1d72440-ac45-48dc-b942-df086a657126 Report Status: 268435456 Hashed
> bucket: 35cf8a512d8cb87c85b17c7c8e03db81 Cab Guid: 0

I've try the get information with the WinDbg tool. But there so much information that I can't find real clues.

But here the WinDbg telling me:

```
************* Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories **************
   ExtensionRepository : Implicit
   UseExperimentalFeatureForNugetShare : false
   AllowNugetExeUpdate : false
   AllowNugetMSCredentialProviderInstall : false
   AllowParallelInitializationOfLocalRepositories : true

   -- Configuring repositories
      ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true
      ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories completed, duration 0.000 seconds

************* Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize **************

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize completed, duration 0.360 seconds
   ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true, Packages count: 0
   ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true, Packages count: 36

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.25877.1004 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

*** wait with pending attach

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00007ff6`25450000 00007ff6`25459000   image00007ff6`25450000
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e2550000 00007ffd`e2765000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e1e00000 00007ffd`e1ec4000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffd`dfb60000 00007ffd`dff04000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`541a0000 00007ffd`55755000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\SolutionsLaumieinc.Frisk-BetaEdition_0.1.11.0_x64__he4x4rq7qkny4\Frisk.Beta.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e0030000 00007ffd`e0197000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\crypt32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`dff10000 00007ffd`e0021000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`89620000 00007ffd`8a2ed000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2_2.2.29512.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\SharedLibrary.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`cc9c0000 00007ffd`cca46000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2_2.2.28604.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mrt100_app.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e0e70000 00007ffd`e0f1e000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\advapi32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e0f20000 00007ffd`e10be000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e1640000 00007ffd`e19ca000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e19f0000 00007ffd`e1a97000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e01a0000 00007ffd`e023a000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e1b80000 00007ffd`e1c97000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e13e0000 00007ffd`e1484000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e13b0000 00007ffd`e13d9000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e0240000 00007ffd`e0266000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e1120000 00007ffd`e1191000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\ws2_32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`dfa40000 00007ffd`dfb59000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e0340000 00007ffd`e04ee000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`df1c0000 00007ffd`df1ee000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e1aa0000 00007ffd`e1b77000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\OleAut32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`bf860000 00007ffd`bf87b000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.32530.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\VCRUNTIME140_APP.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`df1f0000 00007ffd`df218000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\BCrypt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`dd750000 00007ffd`dd88e000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`e1520000 00007ffd`e1528000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\Normaliz.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`de3b0000 00007ffd`de3dd000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\iphlpapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`debb0000 00007ffd`debf2000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sspicli.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffd`df560000 00007ffd`df56a000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DPAPI.DLL
(1ad0.173c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ffd`e262cea4 cc              int     3
```

My intuition leads me to think that the Store App requires some security settings to allow full access to local drive. But I cant find any.

Any help would be welcome

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful: [Files, folders, and libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/) and [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

Comment: Could you please create a sideload package in Release mode for testing, so that we can judge whether it is a problem with the Store.

Comment: Strangely when I manually install with the "Add-AppDevPackage.ps1" the app work in "Debug" mode but not in "Release" mode.

Comment: Will there be an error when running directly with release mode in Visual Studio?

Comment: I discover that as soon as I hit the Windows.Storage namespace such as folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync(), the application Crash and close. I think that I need to add some declaration to the Manifest. I now have to findout witch/what.

Comment: Do you test the folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync() when running from VS in release mode?

Comment: It work fine in Debug or Release mode.

Comment: I've added some "debug" panel winthin my App, so I can better isolate problems and It's look like that running async with .ConfigureAwait(false) didn't always work and crash the app. Also, when deployed on Windows 10 22h2 the FolderPicker (witch work fine on Win11) also crash the app. I'm currently trying to figure out how to fix the FolderPicker.

Comment: Finally here the exact exception: System.Exception: Unspecified error

   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ThrowOnExternalCallFailed(Int32, RuntimeTypeHandle) + 0x21
   at __Interop.ComCallHelpers.Call(__ComObject, RuntimeTypeHandle, Int32, Void*) + 0xbe
   at __Interop.ForwardComStubs.Stub_3[TThis, TResult](__ComObject, Int32) + 0x37
   at Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync() + 0x18
   at Frisk.Main.Test.TestModel.<CreateFolderPicker>d__4.MoveNext() + 0xc1

Comment: It appear that a file filter need to be added. 
            var folderPicker = StorageExtension.CreateFolderPicker();
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fix the issues.
It was kind of simple at the end.
I simply removed the **.ConfigureAwait(false)** from Async calls and added a file type filter to the FolderPicker folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*"), because FolderPicker kept crash the app on Windows 10 22H2, but not on Windows 11 22H2.

`var folderPicker = StorageExtension.CreateFolderPicker();  folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*") // Added this line`

and no need for *broadFileSystemAccess* Capabilitie, so I removed

```
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
  </Capabilities>
```